# visual-studio-2010 convert the Arabic words to not readable code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arabic

Visual studio 2010 convert the Arabic words in my asp code designer to code like this :

&# 1575 ; &# 1604 ; &# 1600 ; &# 1578; &# 1575; &# 1585; &# 1610; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1600; &# 1582;

can any one know how to retrieve or display the Arabic words.

Comment: Could be wrong encoding.Please post some code about how you work with the text.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there might be some encoding problem of your text data. It is hard to say much if we do not know anything about code.

Did read this correctly that you are using ASP.NET?
The this might help: [Displaying Arabic Numbers](http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/27/displaying-arabic-number.aspx)

Also, have a look at this Stack Overflow question:
[Arabic presentation forms B support in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758233/arabic-presentation-forms-b-support-in-c-sharp)

Here is an article with some basic settings that might need to be done in Windows Forms application to display Arabic texts in the UI:
[Multilingual Support in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1134/Multilingual-Support-in-C)
Here you might find some settings that may need to be set on the UI controls.